# create multidimensional json array from a json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a json data. Now I want to reform it. In my json data there is a property like **person_on_zone** I want to make a property named **person_info** and store them which person under this area.

Here is my data any code. Thanks in advance

My json data

```
$val = [
    {
     'city':'xx',
     'zone':'yy',
     'person_on_zone':'p1'
    },
    {
     'city':'xx',
     'zone':'yy',
     'person_on_zone':'p2'
    },
    {
     'city':'xx',
     'zone':'yy',
     'person_on_zone':'p3'
    },
    {
     'city':'xx',
     'zone':'ww',
     'person_on_zone':'p1'
    },
  ]
```

My expectation is

```
[
 {
  'city':'xx',
  'zone':'yy',
  'person_info':{
                  'person_on_zone':'p1',
                  'person_on_zone':'p2',
                  'person_on_zone':'p3',
                }
 },
 {
  'city':'xx',
  'zone':'ww',
  'person_info':{
                  'person_on_zone':'p1'
                }
 },
]
```

Here I tried

```
foreach ($val as $v) {
    $new_array['city'] = $v['city'];
    $new_array['zone'] = $v['zone'];
    foreach ($val as $v2) {
        $new_array['person_info'] = $v['person_on_zone'];
    }
}
json_encode($new_array);
```

Comment: I think you have to change in inner loop like this foreach ($val as $v2){
                        $new_array['person_info'] = $v2['person_on_zone'];
                    }

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, can you please correct this code ?

Comment: is $val json string

Comment: You cannot have one key multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use `$map` to store key `city-zone`, then transform to array to get the result

```
<?php

$val = [
    [
        'city' => 'xx',
        'zone' => 'yy',
        'person_on_zone' => 'p1'
    ],
    [
        'city' => 'xx',
        'zone' => 'yy',
        'person_on_zone' => 'p2'
    ],
    [
        'city' => 'xx',
        'zone' => 'yy',
        'person_on_zone' => 'p3'
    ],
    [
        'city' => 'xx',
        'zone' => 'ww',
        'person_on_zone' => 'p1'
    ]
];

$map = [];
foreach ($val as $v) {
    $key = $v['city'] . $v['zone'];
    if (!isset($map[$key])) {
        $map[$key] = [
            'city' => $v['city'],
            'zone' => $v['zone'],
            'person_info' => []
        ];
    }

    $map[$key]['person_info'][] = $v['person_on_zone'];
}

print_r(array_values($map));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working but it shows **'0':'p1'** . I need 'person_on_zone':'p1'. Please

Comment: can not use duplicate key `person_on_zone` in `person_info` @mrmithun

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code

```
  foreach ($val as $v){
                    $new_array['city'] = $v['city'];
                    $new_array['zone'] = $v['zone'];
                    foreach ($val as $v2){
                        $new_array['person_info'] = $v2['person_on_zone'];
                    }
                }
                json_encode($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**first decode json array then use foreach loop with key**

```
$val = json_decode($val);
foreach ($val as $v){
         $new_array['city'] = $v->city;
         $new_array['zone'] = $v->zone;
         foreach ($val as $key=>$v2){
         $new_array[$key]['person_info'] = $v->person_on_zone;
                    }
                }
 print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you make a mistake around composing the json. I tried with your code and i found following is the correct way to do.. **Remember single quote(') is not  valid in json string that is being used to define key value pair in php**

```
// I think your code has json string and i convert it into array of objects(stdClass) 
// and if your code has array then keep you code intact but need to change the notation of 
// objects to associative array.

// first thing first decode json string
$values =  json_decode('[
{ "city":"xx",
  "zone":"yy",
  "person_on_zone":"p1"
},
{
 "city":"xx",
 "zone":"yy",
 "person_on_zone":"p2"
},
{
 "city":"xx",
 "zone":"yy",
 "person_on_zone":"p3"
},
{
 "city":"xx",
 "zone":"ww",
 "person_on_zone":"p1"
}]');

// Now declare new values as array
$new_values = [];
// walk through each object
foreach ($values as $v){
    // $v becomes an object of stdClass here
    // $data is a temporary array
    $data['city'] = $v->city;
    $data['zone'] = $v->zone;
    $data['person_info'] = [];
    foreach ($values as $v2){
        if(!in_array($data['person_info'],['person_on_zone' => $v2->person_on_zone]))
        {
            // compare if zones are same or not
            if($v->zone == $v2->zone)
            {
                // push to the array instead of assiging
                array_push($data['person_info'], ['person_on_zone' => $v2->person_on_zone]);
            }
        }

    }
    // make array unique 
    $data['person_info'] = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data['person_info'])));
    array_push($new_values, $data);
}
// make array unique in mutidimensional array
$new_values = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $new_values)));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_values);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple foreach would do,

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    //created unique combination of city and zone as key
    $result[$value['city'] . $value['zone']]['city']          = $value['city'];
    $result[$value['city'] . $value['zone']]['zone']          = $value['zone'];
    $result[$value['city'] . $value['zone']]['person_info'][] = ['person_on_zone' => $value['person_on_zone']];
}
echo json_encode(array_values($result));die;
```

[array_values](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) — Return all the values of an array

[**Working demo**](https://3v4l.org/oa3rr).